# Pygame is slow after windows update

Tags: python, pygame

I updated windows to the latest version yesteday, when pygame was working fine. After this update, pygame is very laggy compared to before, despite not adding any code to my project. I've tried restarting my computer, deleting and redownloading pygame, but it still doesn't work. Has anyone got any ideas? Python in general still is as fast as usual

Answer (score 3):

I would go to windows update history and remove the updates then try the game again this way you will know for sure if the windows update affected the game performance.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I've found out why it was slow, the background makes the game strangely laggy for some reason, and taking it out fixes it

Comment: You are welcome. I would have been surprised that a windows update would change anything.